# Increase the weight of a transit line using the transit layer - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to generate a map of Boston using the Google Maps API v3 where the public transit train rails are shown in their proper color (red, green, orange, etc.) but be able to change the size/weight of the lines. When using `google.maps.MapTypeStyler` I can adjust the size of all of the transit lines, not just the rails.

Essentially, I want to increase the size of the transit layer:

```
var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
transitLayer.setMap(map);
```

Above is the code I have currently that adds a really nice layout of all the subway lines but again, I have no way to manipulate their size. Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/styling-the-base-map) for styling the base map.

Comment: @DivijBindlish that's where I looked first, but there are only options to style all transit lines, not just subway rail

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of options available on the [transitLayer class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#TransitLayer) (no properties, two methods)

```
TransitLayer class

google.maps.TransitLayer class

A transit layer.

This class extends MVCObject.

Constructor
TransitLayer()  A layer that displays transit lines.
Methods
getMap()    
Return Value:  Map
Returns the map on which this layer is displayed.
setMap(map:Map) 
Return Value:  None
Renders the layer on the specified map. If map is set to null, the layer will be removed.
```

Your options would be to use a KmlLayer, FusionTablesLayer or a google.maps.Polyline objects to render the data.